# User is charged but doesn't get access to Paid content Xamarin Forms InAppBilling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a Xamarin Forms app in which I used InAppBilling plugin to do in-app purchases. Customers can buy consumables from within the app using app.

- App calls CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync() to purchase an item from Apple in-app purchase.
- After completing the purchase, we take information returned from Apple like purchased and send another call to database to keep a record of the purchase in our database. Function is AddPayment().  Which in return grants user the access to the item what he paid for.

Some users say that they have paid the price but they never got access to the content. Is this a bug in this plugin or do I need something to do at my side. Below is my function to purchase an item:

```
public async Task Purchase()
    {
        try
        {
            var productId = GetProductId(courseDetails.price);

            var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user
                Settings.Message = "Could not connect to billing right now, it could be offline. Try again later.";
                return;

            }
          
          var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, "apppayload");

            // check if failed
            if (purchase == null)
            {
                // Not purchased, alert the user
                await home.DisplayAlert("Error", "Could not complete your purchase. Please try again.", "Ok");
            }
            // SUCCESSFULL, add into the database. 
            else if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
            {
                //Purchased, save this information
                var id = purchase.Id;
                string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(purchase);

                // send an API call to save record to DB
                var result = AddPaymentToDB(id, serializedObject).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                
                await home.DisplayAlert("Success", "You have successfully purchased this course. Your payment ID is :" + purchase.Id, "Ok");
                IsReady = true;
                await LoadPaidContent(result.data);
            }
            isProcessingPaymentRequest = false;
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.PurchaseError)
            {
                case PurchaseError.AppStoreUnavailable:
                    await home.DisplayAlert("Error", "Currently the app store seems to be unavailble. Try again later.", "Ok");
                    break;
                case PurchaseError.BillingUnavailable:
                    await home.DisplayAlert("Error", "Billing seems to be unavailable, please try again later.", "Ok");
                    break;
                case PurchaseError.PaymentInvalid:
                    await home.DisplayAlert("Error", "Payment seems to be invalid, please try again.", "Ok");
                    break;
                case PurchaseError.PaymentNotAllowed:
                    await home.DisplayAlert("Error", "Payment does not seem to be enabled/allowed, please try again.", "Ok");
                    break;

                case PurchaseError.UserCancelled:
                    break;

                default:
                    await home.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
                    break;
            }
            isProcessingPaymentRequest = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isProcessingPaymentRequest = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
            await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
            isProcessingPaymentRequest = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hi, do you mean that some users not keep a record of the purchase in database after completing the purchase?

Comment: Somehow yes. It is successful in more than 90% cases. But I wonder If API call fails somehow or what happens but I have added a check to save purchase info into local storage even if database call fails. So that, user could load the content by opening the app at later time without paying the content coz they have already paid. This works fine in sandbox environment. But in production somehow for very few people, it fails.

Comment: Okey, if you could catch the failure logs, it will be helpful to check where problem is.